# Android Studio will not load on a Samsung ARM Chromebook with 32 bit Ubuntu 12.04 w/ JDK-8

Tags: arm, ubuntu-12.04, android-studio, chromebook

Android Studio 0.2.2 with jdk-8-ea-b102-linux-arm-vfp-hflt-07_aug_2013 will not load on my Samsung ARM Chromebook running 32 bit Ubuntu 12.04. I have tried older JDKs (7 & 6) no luck. JDK-8 says it's ARM compatible. Anyone have else have any luck running this kind of setup?

> /Downloads/android-studio/bin$ ./studio.sh
>   WARNING: You are launching the IDE using OpenJDK Java runtime.
>
> ```
>     IT'S KNOWN TO HAVE PERFORMANCE AND GRAPHICS ISSUES!
>      SWITCH TO THE ORACLE(SUN) JDK BEFORE REPORTING PROBLEMS!
> ```
>
> NOTE:    If you have both Oracle (Sun) JDK and OpenJDK installed
>            please validate either STUDIO_JDK, JDK_HOME, or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid Oracle (Sun) JDK installation.
>            See [ow.ly/6TuKQ](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.1/system-requirements-and-installation.html?origin=old_help#h2linux) for more info on switching default JDK.
>
> Press Enter to continue.

Comment: Ever find a way to run Intellij Idea on Samsung Chromebook Arm? So far, I've successfully got Eclipse running with JDK 8 early release for Arm on Ubuntu using Crouton. I also can run Intellij Idea Community Edition for Arm on Arch Linux using Chroagh and Open-JDK 7 for Arm one time.... after the first time it runs, it will never run again. Neither the idea.log, nor any logs in Arch indicate why Intellij stops working. I have not been running Android Plugin for Eclipse or Android-Studio on Ubuntu or Arch Linux.

Answer (score 1):

When using Chroagh and Arch Linux, Intellij Idea works. At the command line, enter:

```
cd /usr/lib
sudo ln -s libgif.so libgif.so.4
pacman -S intellij-idea-community-edition
```

Intellij Idea install with Open-JDK7 with ARM, but you can replace it with Oracle JDK 8 for ARM.

I have had no luck installing Android-Studio or the Android SDK for Eclipse on either Ubuntu or Arch. Still searching for this solution.